# Checkout all files from branch, without changing HEAD nor existing files

Tags: git

What is the best way to checkout/merge all files from a branch into the working directory, that currently do not exist there, but without changing the repository state, HEAD, or existing files?

Is this possible with a one line command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git diff --name-status HEAD <otherBranch> | grep -e "^A" | cut -f 2 | xargs git checkout <otherBranch> --
```

Does the job.

Comment: This fails for files whose names include spaces.

Answer (score 24):

`git checkout` can take paths as an argument, which, if given, leaves `HEAD` alone, and just checks out those paths into your working directory and index, so you can just use:

`git checkout branchname -- .`

Comment: Hi Anish, unfortunately this is not an answer to my question because git checkout would change existing files in the working directory as well.

Comment: @BlackEye why not `git stash`, run Anish's suggested command, then `git stash pop`?

Comment: @Daniel git stash would only store uncommited changes compared to HEAD

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [git worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree).

With `git worktree add <checkout_path> <otherBranch>` you can checkout the given branch to the given path.

Answer (score 0):

Create additional clone of used local repo and checkout/merge in it. It will be really **The Easiest Way (tm)**